# Add foreign key to one-to-one model (Extended User Model)

Tags: python, django

My porpouse is allow users from Client model to login.

I extended User model with one-to-one relationship as Django [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) says.

Client model:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False, default='example@example.com')
```

Extended User:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ExtendedUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    # client = models.ForeignKey('Client', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'extended_user'
```

On Client table (mysql) I have rows.

When I use `python manage.py migrate` terminal shows me `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1215, 'Cannot add foreign key constraint')`.

If I don't write ForeignKey line it don't have error, but I need this ForeignKey.

What is wrong here? I tried different parameters on ForeignKey line but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to refer to the class name, i.e.: to **Client** instead of User

```
class ExtendedUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(Client, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```